# How can I stretch Cocos2d-x 3.0 buttons to fit their text content?

Tags: cocos2d-x

Cocos2d-x 3.0 buttons have 'scale9' stretching. Can anybody tell me how to scale the button to fix the text on the button? We want to localize our game, so the size of our buttons needs to depend on the size of the text within the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both your Button and Label have a `contentSize().width` and `contentSize().height`

I would get those sizes for your Label and then make your button at least that size plus some padding.

Here's an example, using a lambda that accepts a `Button*` and sets the content size to 1.1f times the Label's size.

```
auto resize_btn = [](ui::Button* button) {
    auto lbl_size = button->getTitleRenderer()->getContentSize();

    button->setContentSize(
        Size(
            lbl_size.width * 1.1f,
            lbl_size.height * 1.1f
        )
    );
};
```

Comment: I had to first call button->ignoreContentAdaptWithSize(false) before button->setContentSize to get the button to respect the new size after setting a texture.  If you look at the code for setContentSize it ignores the size setting if _ignoreSize is true and this gets set after calling loadTextures on the button